# Inplace permutation of a numpy arrray

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy

I have a quite large numpy array of one dimension for which I would like to apply some sorting on a slice inplace and also retrieve the permutation vector for other processing.

However, the ndarray.sort() (which is an inplace operation) method does not return this vector and I may use the ndarray.argsort() method to get the permutation vector and use it to permute the slice. However, I can't figure out how to do it inplace.

```
Vslice = V[istart:istop]  # This is a view of the slice

iperm = Vslice.argsort()

V[istart:istop] = Vslice[iperm]  # Not an inplace operation...
```

Subsidiary question : Why the following code does not modifies V as we are working on a view of V ?

```
Vslice = Vslice[iperm]
```

Best wishes !

François

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question of why assignment to view does not modify the original:

You need to change `Vslice = Vslice[iperm]` to `Vslice[:] = Vslice[iperm]` otherwise you are *assigning* a new value to `Vslice` rather than *changing* the values inside `Vslice`:

```
>>> a = np.arange(10, 0, -1)
>>> a
array([10,  9,  8,  7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1])
>>> b = a[2:-2]
>>> b
array([8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3])
>>> i = b.argsort()
>>> b[:] = b[i]  # change the values inside the view
>>> a            # note `a` has been sorted in [2:-2] slice
array([10,  9,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  2,  1])
```

Comment: Do note that, even though the result is written back to the original array, the operation is not happening "in-place": a copy of the subarray in sorted order is made, and then its contents are written back to the original array.

Comment: @Jaime that is true. this was supposed to answer the last question in the post